# How to redirect user to homepage.php when using PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

First of all, let me explain how my system works. I create the homepage of system using standard php. But, to display the online quiz, i am using a framework which is PHP CI. I've problems when the user completely answer the online question, i need to redirect them to homepage. However, i can't do that because of different medium used which is between standard PHP and PHP CI.

Let me show you what I currently doing. 
result_display.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<div id="container">
<h1>Welcome to Online Examination</h1>

<?php $score =0; ?>

<?php $array1 = array(); ?>
<?php $array2 = array(); ?>
<?php $array3 = array(); ?>
<?php $array4 = array(); ?>
<?php $array5 = array(); ?>
<?php $array6 = array(); ?>
<?php $array7 = array(); ?>
<?php $array8 = array(); ?>
<?php $array9 = array(); ?>

<?php foreach($checks as $checkans) { ?>
    <?php array_push($array1, $checkans); } ?>

<?php foreach($results as $res) { ?>
    <?php array_push($array2, $res->answer);
          array_push($array3, $res->quizID);
          array_push($array4, $res->question1);
          array_push($array5, $res->choice1);
          array_push($array6, $res->choice2);
          array_push($array7, $res->choice3);
          array_push($array8, $res->choice4);
          array_push($array9, $res->answer);
    } ?>


<?php 
    for ($x=0; $x <11; $x++) { ?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Questions/resultdisplay">

<p><?=$array3[$x]?>.<?=$array4[$x]?></p>

<?php if ($array2[$x]!= $array1[$x]) { ?>

    <p><span style="background-color: #FF9C9E"><?=$array1[$x]?></span></p>
    <p><span style="background-color: #ADFF84"><?=$array2[$x]?></span></p>

<?php } else { ?>   


    <p><span style="background-color: #FF9C9E"><?=$array1[$x]?></span></p>

    <?php $score = $score + 1; ?>


    <?php } } ?>

<br>

<h2>Your Result: </h2>
<h1><?=$score?>/11</h1>
<br><br>
 <a href="homepage.php">Back to Homepage

</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The link which is Back to Homepage could not redirect user back to homepage. Is anybody knows how to code it well ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why all the start and stop tags for the php interpreter `<?php .. ?>`

Answer (score 4):

Close the anchor tag like this

```
<a href="homepage.php">Back to Homepage</a>
                       The missing bit ^^^^
```

Or in Codeigniter code I would expect to see something like this,

```
<a href='<?php echo base_url('<controllername>'); ?>'>Back to Homepage</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Homepage**

Problem :  Back to Homepage

In your piece of code You **can’t close anchor tag** so it’s can’t be redirected.

Answer (score 0):

For simply back to previous page use this

1. First load this library

   ```
   $this->load->library('user_agent');
   ```
2. And then use this

   ```
   redirect($this->agent->referrer());
   ```